# Explain the list values transformation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x

x[1] = 'AB'
y[1] = y[1][0]

print(x, y)
>>>
[1, 'A', 3] [1, 'A', 3]
```

We assign 'AB' value to index 1 for x list so y list gets this value as well. Then we assign y[1][0] value to y[1], but what does y[1][0] notation mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y[1]` is the second item from your list, that is 'AB' which is a string. As strings allow you to access its values with indexes, `y[1][0]` is just the first item from the string 'AB', that is 'A'.

See this for [an introduction to Python's strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

`val = y[1][0]`  gets you the same result as

```
 

tmp = y[1]
val = tmp[0]
```

Comment: while true Im not sure this helps the OP much

Comment: it exactly answers the question "what does y[1][0] notation mean?"

Answer (score 0):

`x[1] = "AB"` also assigns `y[1] = "AB"` since x and y are the same list

`y[1] = "AB"` therefore `y[1][0] = 'A'`

see if this helps

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x

print "Y",y
print "X",x
x[1] = 'AB'
print "Y[1]",y[1]
print "Y[1][0]",y[1][0]
y[1] = y[1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a slice of a slice.

```
>>>a = ["a", ["b", ["c"]]]
>>> print a[1][1][0]
'c'
```